# The method mj_reloadData will results in cycling issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The  method mj_reloadData will results in cycling issue?

```
@implementation UICollectionView (MJRefresh)

+ (void)load
{
    [self exchangeInstanceMethod1:@selector(reloadData) method2:@selector(mj_reloadData)];
}

- (void)mj_reloadData
{
    [self mj_reloadData];

    [self executeReloadDataBlock];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be an infinite call and after 10 seconds or so your app will crash if you are calling this on main thread.